# Overriding extensions directory in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

One can specify the extension dir by running from command line:
`code --extensions-dir c:\path\to\ext`

However, I would like to set this parameter even when running from the windows menu.
I tried to modify the argv.json file located in the .vscode folder (like for https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales).
It didn't work.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Bests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating an environment variable called `VSCODE_EXTENSIONS` with the value of `c:\path\to\ext`

Comment: Where is this environment variable documented?

Comment: I've had a look at the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode)

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to DG's response

If the **VSCODE_EXTENSIONS** environment variable is created as a system variable, it seems to affect all users.

In my case, I performed the following steps:

- close VSCode on all users (I usually have one session open as
  administrator and another as non-administrator)
- set the variable **VSCODE_EXTENSIONS** = c:\ProgramData\Code\extensions\
- moved all extensions from the extensions folder of the administrator to c:\ProgramData\Code\extensions\
- restart the computer
- log in with both users and the extensions were available

It is convenient to mention since then the extensions installed by administrator are available to all users and are installed in the folder mentioned previously.

Comment: Where is this environment variable documented?

Comment: @MrWhite it seems to just be in code. See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/a5f84617e22e6e32afc18a808828f1e233361244/src/vs/platform/environment/node/environmentService.ts#L121). Looks like they only read from your home directory after going through other options and this is one of them. Needless to say, it is undocumented API, so be careful using it.